# Testing uniqueness validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to learn rspec and have ran into a problem, I'm trying to test the uniqueness validation on one of my models, but the test keeps failing even though I'm pretty sure it should pass.

Here is my test:

```
  context "two products with the same title" do
    Given{FactoryGirl.build(:product, title: "Hello test title")}
    Given(:post2){FactoryGirl.build(:product, title: "Hello test title")}
    Then{post2.invalid?}
  end
```

and here is my validator:

```
validates :title, uniqueness: true
```

however when I run the test it comes back failed and I'm not sure why?

any help would be great!

Comment: Where is the validation of uniqueness? You are just validating minimum length of the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add uniqueness validation on `title`:

```
validates :title, uniqueness: true
```

And also you have to `create` first `product` not just `build` it

```
context "two products with the same title" do
  Given{FactoryGirl.create(:product, title: "Hello test title")}
  Given(:post2){FactoryGirl.build(:product, title: "Hello test title")}
  Then{post2.invalid?}
end
```

This will create one product with `title =  "Hello test title"`

And for second product with same `title` product will be `invalid`

Comment: Sorry I do have 'validates :title, uniqueness: true' I just copied the wrong line

Comment: still the second thing you need to change

Comment: you need to create first product instead of build

Comment: Thanks, I changed to what you posted and now I get the error

Comment: Failure/Error: Given{FactoryGirl.create(:product, title: "Hello test title")}
     
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Title has already been taken

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to all this how would I do that?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497134/rspec-clean-database-before-running

Answer (score 0):

You should use a gem like shoulda-matchers for testing this kind of tests: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers
It will save you a lot of time and it will DRY your tests (since they are all the same)

Regarding your test, I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. You are not validating uniqueness there, only length of the product. For adding the uniqueness you add to your Product model:

```
validates :title, uniqueness: true
```

And when making the tests, you should create (instead of build) your first Product. Basically, unless your Product is stored in the database, your products will be valid because it doesn't exists (yet) any other Product like that one.

Comment: sorry I did have validates :title, uniqueness: true, I just copied the wrong line

Comment: Common mistake ;) I still highly recommend you to use the gem